# Java selecting MongoDB

Tags: java, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to select a Mongo Database with Java.
I'm using MongoDB shell version v3.6.3 and Java 12.0.1
The problem is, that I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.mongodb.MongoDatabaseImpl cannot be cast to class com.mongodb.DB (com.mongodb.MongoDatabaseImpl and com.mongodb.DB are in unnamed module of loader 'app')at main.java.db_connector.connect(db_connector.java:18)
at main.java.login_gui$1.actionPerformed(login_gui.java:66)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

My code is this:

```
package main.java;

import javax.swing.*;

import com.mongodb.*;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;


import java.util.Arrays;
public class db_connector {
    public static void connect() {
        //DB Connector
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
        MongoCursor<String> dbsCursor = mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().iterator();
        while(dbsCursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(dbsCursor.next());
        }
        DB database = (DB) mongoClient.getDatabase("pipa_db");




    }
}
```

I already realised, that there is some deprecated code like "getDB". Instead I'm using getDatabase.

I wouldn't be surprised if someone else already has asked this question, however I can't find any answer.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should share your mongodb driver's version.

Comment: That would be MongoDB shell version v3.6.3

Comment: No. I mean the MongoDB java driver version

Comment: Oh my bad. That would be mongo-java-driver-3.4.3

Comment: just because mongoClient.getDatabase return a instance of class MongoDatabaseImpl. MongoDatabaseImpl and DB is two different class, so can't cast MongoDatabaseImpl to DB. you should use MongoDatabaseImpl instead of casting it to DB

Comment: I don't understand sorry.

Comment: He means change `DB database = (DB) mongoClient.getDatabase("pipa_db");` to `MongoDatabaseImpl database = mongoClient.getDatabase("pipa_db");`

Comment: Where do I get MongoDatabaseImpl

Comment: I just get this: com.mongodb.MongoDatabaseImpl is not public cannot be accessed outside this package

Comment: Just use ```MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("pipa_db");```